# How to create a column with updated max in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to create a column with the max of the value in column A and the value of the row before of column B. This will provide a list of max values which is updated over the time.

[image: Example in excel]

I was thinking writing this code:

```
SPY['Peak Equity']=SPY['Close price']-SPY['Peak Equity'].shift(-1)
```

but it doesn't work.

Could you please help me? Many thanks in advance!

Yes I'm a beginner ... :-)

Comment: Please [do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), add the information as text (within code fences etc.) instead.

Comment: what is the output you get?

Answer (score 0):

I think `expanding` is what you are looking for.

`SPY['Peak Equity'] = SPY['Close Price'].expanding(1).max()`

You can see detail of `expanding` function here: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear, but it seems like you're looking for [`.cummax()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cummax.html):

With a `df` like

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 4, 7]})
```

```
   A
0  2
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  1
5  5
6  4
7  7
```

this

```
df["B"] = df["A"].cummax()
```

gives you

```
   A  B
0  2  2
1  1  2
2  2  2
3  3  3
4  1  3
5  5  5
6  4  5
7  7  7
```